# Xcode English Localization doesn't use Main.String(english)

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, storyboard

I have three Localization in my App,

Chinese,Japanese are worked perfectly, included Localizable.string and Main.string

..English have a weird problem, Localizable.string(english) works perfect, 
the NSLocalizedString(:) show exactly right String which in Localizable.string(english)

but UI still show the content of my Main.Storyboard(Base) which is chinese,
the Main.String(english) didn't work at all.

I have removed Main.String(english) and localization it again, still not working

Comment: it's a shame no one ever replied on this. I'm working on i18n in Angular at this point in time...